# "rails server" using the wrong database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, amazon-rds

I recently switched a relatively new rails app from sqlite3 to Amazon RDS and configured my `database.yml` file to use the RDS database in the production environment only.

But now, whenever I try to do any local action on my database (e.g. `rails server`, `rails console`, `rake db:migrate`, etc.) it does that action to the production DB on Amazon's servers rather than my local sqlite3 DB, which is my development DB.

```
# database.yml

development:
    adapter: sqlite3
    database: db/development.sqlite3
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

test:
    adapter: sqlite3
    database: db/test.sqlite3
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

production:
    adapter: mysql2
    host: mydb.mydbhost.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
    reconnect: false
    database: mydb
    username: myusername
    password: mypassword
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Here's my environment.rb file:

```
# environment.rb

# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Heroku environment variables for local use
heroku_env = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'heroku_env.rb')
load(heroku_env) if File.exists?(heroku_env)

# Initialize the rails application
Myapp::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: See if you have a environment variable called RAILS_ENV and if it is defined as production. You can do that opening a shell and typing echo $RAILS_ENV

Comment: nope no $RAILS_ENV environment variable :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem after taking a day to get away from it. It's a silly mistake on my part, but I thought I'd post the solution in case someone else encounters a similar issue.

As you can see from my environment.rb file above, I have a `heroku_env.rb` file, which contains all of my heroku-specific environment variables on my local machine for development purposes. In that file, I declared a `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` variable, which links to my Amazon RDS database. Deleting this from the file solved the problem!

Thanks to everyone who offered answers to help!

Comment: Hey just to help you out, Heroku has settings for all its apps that are configurable via the heroku command line, may be better to use that rather than an initilizer, our workflow is to use ENV['something'] = something in a .rvmrc and then duplicate all those env settings on heroku. Then have an initializer read those ENV[''] settings into Constants for use in the app. Also do not forget to .freeze the ENV when reading them in to avoid run time problems.

Answer (score 0):

your not using productions settings

try

`rails s -e production`

or

`RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to use the production database, I want to use the development one and for some reason whenever I run `rails s` on my local machine it uses the production database.

Comment: can you post your .rvmrc ? assuming you have one?

Comment: i actually don't have one -- could that be the problem?

Comment: no probably not. i just want to make sure the environment wasn't beng set on accident in there.

Comment: Can you confirm your application when running `rails s` is running as the development environment? THat would help isolate the problem as being db config.

Comment: it seems like it's actually loading the development environment (in terms of my asset host settings and stuff), but the database is the production DB for some reason...